# In-app purchases not working shortly after review

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have an [app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exoplanet/id327702034?mt=8) with two in-app purchases. One is called `adfree`, the other `galaxycluster`. The `adfree` product has been working for a long time. In the newest version, I added the `galaxycluster` product. I tested it in the sandbox and submitted it for review together with the app update.

Since the app status changed to `in review`, product requests for `galaxyclusters` fail. I noticed this initially in the sandbox environment and now that the app update has been approved and released, this is still not working in the production environment.

Did anyone else notice something similar? I.e. product requests working in the sandbox, then not working anymore when the app is in review? Should I just wait for 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting (12 hours) did indeed resolve the issue (and created two bad reviews in the meantime).